# Iphone:dismissing view controller and three main views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have a problem which was of course solved but I couldn't find the answer for it.

I have an application which has three main views. In my case it means that 
I have main screen(Screen A) and I can go to screen B or screen C.
I have (screen B) from which I can go to screen A or Screen C.
I have screen C from which I can go to screen A or Screen B.

I don t have a storyboard and I am using presentModalViewController. So I want to dismiss parent every time I switch from child to other screen

*For example:* 
`screen A->screen B`(defore calling screen C screen A is dismissed)`->screen C ->screen A`(screen A created again and screen B is deleted)

I tried to use `[self.presentingModalViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated];` in the button method for other screen call but it throws exception.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: It is better if you give NSExcption information also.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application navigation based? Try this:

```
 YourABCController *controllerObj = [[YourABCController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourABCController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navcont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controllerObj];

[self presentModalViewController:navcont animated:YES];

[commentsViewControllerObj release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can make it as a TabBar based application with three view controller A,B &C then you can easily switch between views

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewControllerA = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewControllerB = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewControllerC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewControllerA, viewControllerB,viewControllerC, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to use a navigationController and push, pop or pop and then push as appropriate.

Or you could use NSNotifications to tell the parent viewController to dismiss it's children:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"switchToViewB" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

and the parent to call it's method switchToViewB when it receives a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(switchToViewB:) name:@"switchToViewB" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Specification says next about -(void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: method:

```
If you call this method on the presented view controller itself,
however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.
If you present several view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of 
presented    view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in
the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers 
above that child on the stack.
```

So if in your example you dismiss ScreenA then ScreenB will be dismissed too.

Instead such approach you can use UINavigationBar, UITabBar or present view controllers by one